# How to monitor delivery of emails sent by salesforce by source code?

Tags: email, salesforce, apex-code

I have following questions. Assuming I have following code

```
public class MessageMaker {
public static void helloMessage() {
System.debug( 'Entry point' );

Case c = new Case();
insert c;

EmailMessage e = new EmailMessage();
System.debug( 'EmailMessage created' );
e.parentid = c.id;
// Set to draft status.
// This status is required 
// for sendEmailMessage().
e.Status = '5'; 
e.TextBody = 
  'Sample email message.';
e.Subject = 'Apex sample';
e.ToAddress = 'my@mail.com';
insert e;

List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> 
  results = 
  Messaging.sendEmailMessage(new ID[] 
    { e.id });
System.debug(results.size());
System.debug(results[0].success);       
System.debug(results[0].getErrors().size());
System.assertEquals(1, results.size());
System.assertEquals(true, results[0].success);
}
}
```

1.First question. I want to find out using apex code if the message was really delivered.
Here documentation says http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_sendemail_emailresult.htm

Even if success = true, it does not mean the intended recipients received the email, as it could have bounced or been blocked by a spam blocker. Also, even if the email is successfully accepted for delivery by the message transfer agent, there can still be errors in the error array related to individual addresses within the email.

So I have been trying to send email by apex code and look for results[0].success. It seems it says like it is described in documentation, so success is true even though email address was incorrect.

Also I have tried to check this manually through email logs http://eu2.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/email_logs.htm

And I have found following row in resulting log regarding my email sent to incorrect address

> 9/2/2013 9:36 66/FC-09306-20B54225 T julfy@i.ia
>   julfy=i.ua__0-6uvic1ltvun1nf@95mngihd2hpe0w.b-ysubea0.bl.bnc.salesforce.com 1434 005b0000000J7bm
>   <_0vTJ000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000MSHRSY00W1-CKg3DShWC5xu24ccHFA@sfdc.net>
>   1 311.627583 421 4.4.0 [internal] no MXs for this domain could be
>   reached at this time

But I don't know how to access this information by apex code. Any thoughts?

1. Second question. If message was delivered and recipient forwarded it, is any possibility to monitor that using apex code? Anybody?

Comment: You can use a tracking pixel with limitations.  The user will need to render the image, which will then call your server for you to log that this email has been read.  As far as pinning deliverability, you won't be able to accurately track all those emails or which email box they went into as users disallow images a lot of the time.  Looks safe?  Show Images?  They click that it would track, if they don't... no tracking.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do either of those things. APEX runs on Salesforce's servers and when you send an email it leaves that environment. The only time you can monitor a successful response is when you're dealing with an API that generates webhooks.

Comment: You can do these things, but it requires using a 1x1 tracking pixel.